# Per group wilcox.test against everything else using two data frame columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Input data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x=abs(rnorm(50)),col1=rep(1:5,10), col2=rep(1:4,25))
```

I want to do:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>%
  < for g in col2 do wilcox.test(.data[.data$col2 == g]$x,.data[.data$col2 != g]$x)$p.value >
```

So what I am not sure is how to implement the part in the brackets. The end result should have three columns: col1, col2, p_value; where the p_value is from the wilcox.test of each group in col2 against all other values outside the group in col2 (within each col1 value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a helper function that takes the x and col2 columns, by group and returns a dataframe with the p values. Then, just call that function using `reframe`, with `.by=col1`

```
f <- \(x,c2) {
  vs <- unique(c2)
  data.frame(col2=vs,p_value=sapply(vs, \(v) wilcox.test(x[c2==v],x[c2!=v])$p.value))
} 

reframe(df, f(x,col2), .by=col1)
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2    p_value
1     1    1 0.08062436
2     1    2 0.44453044
3     1    3 0.16795666
4     1    4 0.67247162
5     2    2 0.02541280
6     2    3 0.14176987
7     2    4 0.80005160
8     2    1 0.73542312
9     3    3 0.73542312
10    3    4 0.86597007
11    3    1 0.19736842
12    3    2 0.49729102
13    4    4 0.30559856
14    4    1 0.14176987
15    4    2 0.11855005
16    4    3 0.34855521
17    5    1 0.26612487
18    5    2 0.14176987
19    5    3 0.05263158
20    5    4 0.49729102
```

Input (notice that I use `rnorm(100)` to avoid recycling):

```
set.seed=123
df <- data.frame(x=abs(rnorm(100)),col1=rep(1:5,10), col2=rep(1:4,25))
```